# Pulling Morningstar data into googlesheet

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets

Ive read around 50 different posts on this but none of the stuff is really working. I am tying to pull NAV from the following fund

https://www.morningstar.se/se/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000LN6Q

Which is on line 513 in view-source:https://www.morningstar.se/se/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000LN6Q

I tried some different commands such at IMPORTXML and IMPORTHTML and INDEX

Any suggestions?

Comment: As i see, there is an intro page for new users (without cookies). May be it is the reason why googlesheet can't find data - because it see intro page, not a data page.

Comment: @MadRay right..it might be..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got this `IMPORTHTML` to work:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://www.morningstar.se/se/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000LN6Q","table",4),2,3)
```

The 4 selects the 4th table element, 2 selects the second row, 3 selects the third column.

Since you're looking at a Swedish site, I'm guessing your locale is Sweden. In that case, you want to use `;` as argument separators instead of `,`:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://www.morningstar.se/se/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000LN6Q";"table";4);2;3)
```